# What is considered that a question is not perceived very well and how does Stack count questions?

Tags: bug

I would ask a question but Stack doesn't allow me to do with the following reason:
My question was not perceived very well.
But I thought that a not well percieved question was caused by downvotes. But that is not the case

Besides that Stack says that I have asked already two questions (besides this one). But I think I have only asked till now one question.

So are there some bugs in Sport Stack, or do I overlook something?

[What is the circumference of the legs of Usain bolt?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/16749/what-is-the-circumference-of-the-legs-of-usain-bolt)

Answer (score 3):

You have in fact asked another question in [February 2017](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/15578/what-is-the-world-record-speed-bicycling-an-hour-on-a-home-trainer) - the question was closed by the community and then deleted by one of the Stack Exchange "clean up" bots. I *think* you can still see your own deleted questions, but if not it certainly is the case. Note that in terms of question bans, deleted questions still count.

Your current question ban here will expire on the 18th August, so I suggest that you wait until then - but then be very sure that the question you're asking is a good question. For what it's worth, neither I nor any of the other moderators here have any influence over question bans - they are an automatic response from the Stack Exchange software.

Comment: thanks, but what is/was the reason that my current question isn't very well received, there were no downvotes?

Comment: Your deleted question has 4 downvotes - I suspect that is more of the problem (Stack Exchange don't make the exact algorithm for question bans available, so I'm guessing as much as you are here).

Comment: And no, you can't see your own deleted question. I posted a question here over a year ago, and with no votes, no answers, 1 comment, and low views after a year the roomba deleted it. There is no trace of it in my history. I just remember that I posted it.

Comment: @PeterCooperJr. Can you see the question [if you follow this link](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/14016/is-a-candlepin-pin-downed-if-it-pops-back-up)? There's a subtle difference between not being able to see the question, and it not appearing on your profile.

Comment: @Philip Yes I can; thanks for that. I hadn't saved a link to the question, so all I had to go on was my profile saying that I hadn't asked any questions.